# How to compare several td.text() in tr using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table>
<tr id="tr1">
<td id="td1"> test1 </td>
<td id="td2"> test2 </td>
<td id="td3"> test1 </td>
<td id="td4"> test3 </td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Here I have a table with a `tr` in it and 4 `td`'s.
Now, my question is, how can I compare the `td.text()` with the other one?

**For example:**
a loop that takes the text of first `td` and then compare it with other `td`'s. 
If it is the same, then give that `td` a class.

**HERE:** `td id="td1"` should get a class

**BUT:**
When I'm at the 3e `td`, the 3e `td` should get a class.

Comment: Please post the JavaScript you've tried.

Comment: that looks like homework....
You should really try to do it yourself. after trying, bring some code and then you'll find help here

Comment: no is not, its a project, i ve tried to copy my script but its too big

Comment: So you're wanting to compare multiple `td` elements, I guess that means the above code should have multiple `td` elements? I don't think this would need a loop, rather just a simple `if` statement.

Comment: Too big? A script to do what you need should be a handful of lines. Try narrowing down the code you have which could also help you troubleshoot the issue, then add it to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work for you:

```
var tds;
$('tr').each(function(i, item){
    tds = $(this).find('td');
    tds.each(function(j, elem1){
        tds.each(function(k, elem2){
            if($(elem1)[0] != $(elem2)[0] && $(elem1).text() == $(elem2).text()){
                $(elem1).addClass('cl');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/cqa6m6va/1/

Comment: thy i will try it out, i was working with each but my elem was wrong

Comment: Thankyou :D with a small touch it worked in my script

Comment: I'm very pleased to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
function setClasses(word) {
var tds = $("tr td");
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    if(tds.eq(i).text() === word) {
        tds.eq(i).addClass('red');
    }
  }   
}
setClasses("test1");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors will be your friend here.   :)

```
var $container = $("#tr")
$container.children().each(function() {
    if (!($(this).hasClass("td")) {
        var sTextVal = $(this).text();
        var $currTextGroup = $container.children(":contains('" + sTextVal + "')");

        if ($currTextGroup.length > 1) {
            $currTextGroup.addClass("td");
        }
    }
});
```

I'll explain the logic, and then touch on one issue to be aware of . . .

Basically, this code:

1. Collects all of the the children of the `<tr>` and loops through them one at a time
2. If the current child does not already have a class of "td" (if it already has a "td" class, then this text has already been checked for duplicates), it retrieves the text from inside the element and searches for all of the children of the `<tr>` that contain that same text value
3. If more than one of the children in the `<tr>` contain that text, all of those children are given the class of "td"

The one potential issue that this solution could run into is if the text in the current element is present as **part of** the text in one of its siblings.  For example, if the text in one sibling is "the", and it has some siblings that have text values of "*the*n" and "*the*re" and "*the* end", they will be found by `:contains`.

If your text values are sufficiently "patterned" (as they are in your example), though, this should not be an issue.  If it is an issue, there is a more complex way to do that "common text" selection, but I won't bother with that, unless it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to select the first 'td' in a 'tr' and compare it against the other 'td' in your table. Please try the below code and let me know if it works for you.

HTML (provided by OP)

```
<table>
    <tr id="tr1">
        <td id="td1"> test1 </td>
        <td id="td2"> test2 </td>
        <td id="td3"> test1 </td>
        <td id="td4"> test3 </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

CSS

```
.color--red { color: red; }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var first = $("#tr1 :first-child").html();
    $('#tr1 :not(:first-child)').each(function() {
        if(first == $(this).html()){
            $(this).addClass("color--red");
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to keep it as simple as possible. The variable first pertains to that first 'td' that you want to use for comparison. Note how the each function operates on 'all elements except the first child in the tr', which clearly will omit the first variable we declared initially. From there it's all about comparing using $(this).html() to grab the value of the currently selected element, against the value obtained from the first variable.

Once this succeeds, simply add a class of your choice. For simplicity's sake, I added my own color--red class to the mix, which should show red color text for the third 'td' element as you suggested in your question post. Enjoy! Let me know if you need anything further.