# How to check for duplicates of select element inside a td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

From the question and demo,

[How to compare several td.text() in tr using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532862/how-to-compare-several-td-text-in-tr-using-jquery)

https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/cqa6m6va/1/

it showed how to determine duplicates within td elements.

My problem is on how to do it within select elements inside a td:

```
<td style="max-width:160px" class="ellipsis">
    <select class="select make-long-select fieldEditable ddSample" style="display:none;" name="sampleName">
        <option value="SampleValue1">SampleValue1</option>
    </select>
    <span class="lblSample lblCurrentValue">SampleValue1</span>
</td>

<td style="max-width:160px" class="ellipsis">
    <select class="select make-long-select fieldEditable ddSample" style="display:none;" name="sampleName">
        <option value="SampleValue2">SampleValue2</option>
    </select>
    <span class="lblSample lblCurrentValue">SampleValue2</span>
</td>

<td style="max-width:160px" class="ellipsis">
    <select class="select make-long-select fieldEditable ddSample" style="display:none;" name="sampleName">
        <option value="SampleValue1">SampleValue1</option>
    </select>
    <span class="lblSample lblCurrentValue">SampleValue1</span>
</td>

<td style="max-width:160px" class="ellipsis">
    <select class="select make-long-select fieldEditable ddSample" style="display:none;" name="sampleName">
        <option value="SampleValue3">SampleValue3</option>
    </select>
    <span class="lblSample lblCurrentValue">SampleValue3</span>
</td>
```

I need to implement the same behavior as the last question to this script.

I tried this approach but no luck:

```
tds = $(this).find('td.ddSample');
tds.each(function(j, elem1){
    tds.each(function(k, elem2){
        if($(elem1)[0] != $(elem2)[0] && $(elem1).text() == $(elem2).text()){
            $(elem1).addClass('cl');
        }
    });
});
```

Note: I only need to compare ddSample data (Assuming I have other data inside tr)

Comment: First things first.. in your JS, are you sure that your variables are holding the correct information?

Comment: Your given fiddle is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqa6m6va/24/)**

used the same JQ you provided but instead of adding a class to the element ( which is the `option` ) i added the class to it's parent (`select`) and then in CSS styled the next `span` with `color:red`

check fiddle above or the snippet below

```js
var opt = $(".ddSample option")


 opt.each(function(j, elem1){
    opt.each(function(k, elem2){
        if($(elem1)[0] != $(elem2)[0] && $(elem1).val() == $(elem2).val()){
            $(elem1).parent(".ddSample").addClass('cl');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.cl + span{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td style="max-width:160px" class="ellipsis">
    <select class="select make-long-select fieldEditable ddSample" style="display:none;" name="sampleName">
        <option value="SampleValue1">SampleValue1</option>
    </select>
    <span class="lblSample lblCurrentValue">SampleValue1</span>
</td>

<td style="max-width:160px" class="ellipsis">
    <select class="select make-long-select fieldEditable ddSample" style="display:none;" name="sampleName">
        <option value="SampleValue2">SampleValue2</option>
    </select>
    <span class="lblSample lblCurrentValue">SampleValue2</span>
</td>

<td style="max-width:160px" class="ellipsis">
    <select class="select make-long-select fieldEditable ddSample" style="display:none;" name="sampleName">
        <option value="SampleValue1">SampleValue1</option>
    </select>
    <span class="lblSample lblCurrentValue">SampleValue1</span>
</td>

<td style="max-width:160px" class="ellipsis">
    <select class="select make-long-select fieldEditable ddSample" style="display:none;" name="sampleName">
        <option value="SampleValue3">SampleValue3</option>
    </select>
    <span class="lblSample lblCurrentValue">SampleValue3</span>
</td>
```

Comment: how do I specify to check only ddSample data? I have other elements in my tr so it compares everything

Comment: If you are refering to the `select` with the class `ddSample` . just change at the begining of the jq...where the var is declared from `.selected option` to `ddSample option`. Will edit my answer in the snippet

Comment: Thanks. Does this loop also get cached elements? I am having performance issues with this loop

Comment: It.s a pretty simple loop. It shouldn.t cause any performance issues. It just compares the values of the options in the select elements and adding a class. Nothing more

Comment: What if the dropdowns have cached values? I think it includes them that is why I am having performance issues

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
var tds;
$('tr').each(function(i, item){
    tds = $(this).find('td');
    tds.each(function(j, elem1){
        tds.each(function(k, elem2){     

            if($(elem1)[0] != $(elem2)[0] && $(elem1).find("select").html() == $(elem2).find("select").html()){
            console.log($(elem1).find("select").html());
                $(elem1).addClass('cl');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/cqa6m6va/20/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

                  $(".ddSample").children().each(function(i,v){
                               $(".ddSample").children().each(function(j,w){
                               if(i!=j){
                                if($(v).val()==$(w).val()){
                                   $(v).parent().next().addClass("cl")
                                 }
                               }

                               });
                 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cqa6m6va/22/